# Use Docker Image as Python interpreter in PyCharm

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

Being a beginner to Docker, I want to know that how can I use a Docker Image ( downloaded from Docker Hub ) as a python interpreter in PyCharm on Windows. I want to run some Python files in PyCharm using the Docker Image. I have downloaded the Docker Integration plugin in my PyCharm.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/docker.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can find a thorough and step by step tutorial in the article
>   provided underneath this Post, this article mainly teach you how to
>   use **Pycharm remote interpreter** (using **Docker**), here you need
>   to pay attention that to use this feature, your Pycharm must be a
>   **Professional** version.

---

## Instruction:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter.html

Comment: So, won't that work in PyCharm Community edition since I am using that ?

Comment: unfortunately not, but still you can manage to use docker in the command line and it's not that complicated.